# Problem to set correct (asked) key AES-256 encryption to a SOAP webservice

Tags: php, encryption, aes

I need to encrypt a password towards a SOAP webinterface, however I don't understand the instructions from the serviceprovider. It states:

*"The commonkey are generated by creating a string  with todays date + current hour. For example 2018-05-1513 is created if the time is 13 in the afternoon and 2018-05-159 is created if the time is 9 in the morning. Time is UTC. The String is then hashed with the SHA256 algoritm. "*

This is pretty simple and I have done it with the following code (PHP):

```
date_default_timezone_set("UTC");
$commonKey = date("Y-m-d");
$commonKey .= date("H");
$commonKey = hash('sha256', $commonKey, true);
```

The AES object that is used to make the encryption is configured with a blocksize of 128 bits with CBC.

However here comes the part i don't understand:

*When the AES object is created a key (256 byte array) and IV (Vector 128 bits bytearray). Those are used in the actually encrypting. As soon as the object is created the IV is saved and you are suppose to set the key to the byteArray that was initially created from todays date + the actually hour hashed with SHA256.
After that the encrypting is done and the chiffertext and IV is sent to the webservice*

I have no clue how to add the key to the byteArray of the commonkey. And I have no clue how the webservice are able to decrypt my password. Are there anyone that can enlight me? Note that key is randomly created but I don't know what to do with it.

The complete code looks like this for the moment:

```
//create commonkey
date_default_timezone_set("UTC");
$key = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(32);

$commonKey = date("Y-m-d");
$commonKey .= date("H");
$commonKey = hash('sha256', $commonKey, true);

$cipher = "aes-128-cbc";

//encrypt password

$iv;

if (in_array($cipher, openssl_get_cipher_methods())){
    $ivlen = openssl_cipher_iv_length($cipher);
    $iv = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes($ivlen);
    $password = openssl_encrypt($password, $cipher, $commonKey, $options=0, $iv);
}

//check if user is allowed to login
if ($check->CheckUserLoginClubEncrypted($username, $password, $iv, $organizationalUnitID) 
!== false) {
    echo "Logged in";
    print_r($check->getResult());

} else {
    echo "Not logged in";
    print_r($check->getLastError());

}
```

Answer (score 0):

the problem was the keysize! :) Finaly done!!